# How to create alias with variable in .cshrc?

Tags: alias, csh

For example, I want to create an alias to remove duplicate lines:

```
alias rm.dup  'perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;''
```

When source .cshrc, it reports: "dup: Undefined variable."

If change it to

```
alias rm.dup  'perl -ne 'print unless \$dup{$_}++;' \!* &'
```

It reports: "!* &: Command not found."

And also tried

```
alias rm.dup  'perl -ne 'print unless \$dup{$_}++;''
```

Reports: ": Command not found."

What's the general rule of using variable with alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alias rm.dup  'perl -ne '\''print unless $dup{$_}++'\'' \!* &'
```

Since one cannot embed a single quote within single quotes, so one way is to break out of the single quote, slip in a literal quote, then restart the quotes.

```
'perl -ne '\''print unless $dup{$_}++'\'' \!* &'
|---------|B |-----------------------|D |------|
     A                   C                  E
```

Another way is:

```
alias rm.dup  'perl -ne "print unless "\$"dup{"\$"_}++" \!* &'
```